# How to hide all elements with a specific attribute set?

Tags: jquery, select, attributes, hide, live

I have a series of items being inserted into my html document via ajax request from a php document.  The data that is returned consists of a bunch of div elements with custom attributes set so that I may be able to tell which div elements belong to which category of items that have been returned.  I would like to be able to click on the category name and hide all elements that have the custom attribute (which is set to the category name).

Sample return

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="category" categoryID="category_1">
      category_1
      <div categoryID="category_1">item 1</div>
      <div categoryID="category_1">item 2</div>
      <div categoryID="category_1">item 3</div>
   </div>
   <div class="category" categoryID="category_2">
      category_2
      <div categoryID="category_2">item 1</div>
      <div categoryID="category_2">item 2</div>
      <div categoryID="category_2">item 3</div>
   </div>
   <div class="category" categoryID="category_3">
      category_3
      <div categoryID="category_3">item 1</div>
      <div categoryID="category_3">item 2</div>
      <div categoryID="category_3">item 3</div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <div class="category" categoryID="category_1">
      category_1
      <div categoryID="category_1">item 1</div>
      <div categoryID="category_1">item 2</div>
      <div categoryID="category_1">item 3</div>
   </div>
   <div class="category" categoryID="category_2">
      category_2
      <div categoryID="category_2">item 1</div>
      <div categoryID="category_2">item 2</div>
      <div categoryID="category_2">item 3</div>
   </div>
   <div class="category" categoryID="category_3">
      category_3
      <div categoryID="category_3">item 1</div>
      <div categoryID="category_3">item 2</div>
      <div categoryID="category_3">item 3</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am using jquery to handle most of the javascript function so naturally I would am using code like below when working with the data that is dynamically added to the dom.

```
$(".skillCategory").live({
        mouseenter:
           function(){
               $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
           },
        mouseleave:
           function(){
               $(this).css('background-color', '#393939');
           }
       });
    $(".skillCategory").live('click',function(){
        var title = $(".skillCategory").attr("categoryID");

        });
});
```

I am trying to be able to hide a category and all of the items in which belong to it as determined by the "categoryID" attribute.

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: i couldn't find what skillCategory class is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, something like this should work:

```
$(".category").live('click',function(){
       var category = $(this).attr("categoryID");
       $("[categoryID=" + category + "]").not('.category').hide();
    });
```

Comment: in the first part where you have $(".category") the .category is discovered through the use of the last piece of code as shown above and now below `$(".skillCategory").live('click',function(){
        var title = $(".skillCategory").attr("categoryID");

        });`  The issue is when I try to use the title variable in place of your .category it does not appear to work.  How do i do this dynamically?

Comment: @wes, can you post the complete html, and i will modify the code. Your examples did not include ,.skillCategory and i had to use .category

Comment: This worked like a charm.  I am unsure what it was that I was doing wrong, but your solution is well written.  Thank you.

Comment: incase anybody reads this and wants to know, replace the .hide() with .toggle()

Answer (score 1):

You could format your HTML to use the new "data attribute" notation:

```
<div class="category" data-categoryID="category_3">
```

Then you can do this:

```
$(".category").click(function() {
  var ctx = $(this);
  $(".category").each(function(item) {
    if($(this).data("categoryID") != ctx.data("categoryID") {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: do most browsers support this?

Comment: `$(".skillCategory").live('click', function() {
        
        var ctx = $(this);
        console.log(ctx);
        $(".skillCategory").each(function(item) {
            console.log("first: ");
            console.log($(this).data("categoryID"));
            console.log("Seccond: ");
            console.log(ctx.data("categoryID"));
            if($(this).data("categoryID") != ctx.data("categoryID")) {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });`  The first log shows all the different categories as expected.  The others produce undefined variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jquery attribute selector : http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

You should combine it with something else to avoid hiding the main div, like ":not(.skillCategory)" or similar.

Comment: I am not having an issue selecting an item in the dynamic content, the issue comes when trying to isolate the "categoryID" and then hide all elements that have that attribute.

Comment: And that is done using the attribute selector, that will find all other elements having a given category id so that you can hide them, as Emil did in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

This sould do it for you :

http://jsfiddle.net/J6PRM/

hope it helps.

Comment: This would be great but the issue i have is when the content is dynamically added you have to use .live.  I will see if I can modify what you have there and see if I can make it work.  Thank you for the suggestion.